# Sequelize select query issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Here I am selecting only two-column.

```
      attributes: ['State','PartnerID'],
      // where: {
      //   PartnerServiceLocationID: 535343,
      //   '$partner.Domain$': 1
      // },
      include: [{
        model: partner,
        as: 'partner',
      }]
    })
```

But It is working as

`select * from ....`

All columns are getting selected.

Comment: can you show the whole sequelize query and SQL query as well?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge `Sequelize` never generates query like `select * from` unless it is a raw query

Comment: select * means it is selecting all columns from tables. I have specified columns still. When I remove include it is selection column from attributes but when include is there all columns getting selected.